# List of PowerPC apps

Tags: macos, applications, powerpc

I'm breathing life again into an "old" MacMini G4 1.5Ghz. Instead of searching each and every one of my favorite apps to check whether there's still an old version that runs on PowerPC / OSX 10.5.8, I was trying to search some kind of "software still running on PowerPC"-list. Something that would gather links to (or would mirror old installers of) the latest PPC-compatible version of a big list of commonly used apps. Something like [iUseThis](http://osx.iusethis.com) but for old versions, or with an advanced search to target only PPC apps.

Does this exist? My google-fu has come to an end here.

Or if it does not exist, do you think it'd be worth providing such a service by writing this kind of database myself? I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one interested in resuscitating old Macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only as a hobby project since PowerPC market is dying.

Try [this filter](http://download.cnet.com/mac/3151-20_4-0.html?filter=os=86%7C&filterName=os=Mac%20OS%20X%2010.5%20PPC%7C&tag=narrow) on the base that once was Version Tracker.
Also you may use [Universal Apps List from Apple](http://web.archive.org/web/20080820104633/http://guide.apple.com/universal) through Wayback Machine

Comment: Damn! download.com! didn't even think of it. I haven't been using it for, well, ages. I'll wait a bit longer to see if there are other answers before marking yours as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.powerpcsoftware.com and http://macpowerpc.com - they list a lot of Mac PPC software.